# OpenCV stitcher fails to stitch undistorted images

Tags: c++, image-stitching, opencv3.1, fisheye

I am trying to stitch a panorama using mobile phone camera with an attachable 170 degree wide angle lens. The resulting photo is distorted (fisheye). I understand that to stitch these photos using `Stitcher::stitch(InputArrayOfArrays images, OutputArray pano)` they must be undistorted first.

First, I did the `undistort(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray cameraMatrix, InputArray distCoeffs, InputArray newCameraMatrix=noArray() )` and save the results to jpg files. Then, I read the jpg images, stitched them to be a panorama image and this worked well.

Next, I joined the process into a single process. So I did not save the undistorted image, but keep them in `cv::Mat` and use it as the stitcher input. This one fails with error code ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS.

My question is, why does it work if the stitcher input (`ImgArray`) comes from `imread`, but fails if the input comes directly from `undistort` output? How to make the second case work?

```
//Load photo source (distorted)
Mat imageDistorted, imageUndistorted;
vector<Mat> ImgArray;

for (int p=1; p<=6; p++){
    imageDistorted = imread( "/file1.jpg" ); //read file2, file3, ...
    if(imageDistorted.data){
        undistort(imageDistorted, imageUndistorted, camVariables, distCoeffs);

        ImgArray.push_back( imageUndistorted );

    }
}

//Apply Stitching algorithm
Mat panoImg;
Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault();

Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(ImgArray, panoImg);
```

Comment: Stitcher returns ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS when it can't find enough features in images to connect them. Saving images as jpegs certainly can add some features by degrading quality, so there is a potential reason for that weird behavior.